# Can't install package ‘ggpmisc’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)

Tags: r, installation, dockerfile, ggpmisc

I'm trying to install ‘ggpmisc’ package in my Dockerfile, and I got the message :

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘ggpmisc’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You've given folks very little information here. Have you checked through previous questions, like this one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/25721884/5325862

Comment: This isn't a dup of that question:  this is a problem with the `cloud.r-project.org` redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cloud.r-project.org` is supposed to be an alias for `cran.rstudio.com`, but it looks as though something has gone wrong with the name service at `r-project.org`.  You could try the real name directly using `install.packages("ggpmisc", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")`.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work...

Comment: The `r-project.org` issue has been fixed; it may take a while for your system to see the fix, but eventually the `unable to access index for repository` message should go away.  The `‘ggpmisc’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)` error may remain; because R 3.5.0 is no longer current, you might have to build the package yourself (or upgrade R).